# Can a person like "tu" be placed as the subject of "déboucher sur"?

Tags: usage

I just said in conversation:

> Voyons, la grande rue de Ginza... Il suffit que **tu** fasses quelque pas vers la gauche pour **déboucher** directement **sur** la porte sud. Facile.

I usually place a word like "rue" as the subject of "déboucher sur", so I'm not sure the use of "tu" as the subject is appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely use *tu* as the subject of *déboucher sur* here. This is a standard usage of *déboucher*.

> Voyons, la grande rue de Ginza... Il suffit que tu fasses quelque pas vers la gauche et tu débouches directement sur la porte sud. Facile.

TLFi : [Déboucher](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9boucher/1)

> **A.−**
>   **1.** Sortir d'un endroit resserré pour passer dans un lieu plus ouvert. **Déboucher dans, sur, à.** *Le moine poussa une autre porte et ils débouchèrent dans un long couloir* (Huysmans, *En route*, t. 2, 1895, p. 269). − *Tiens ! remarqua-t-il, nous voici hors de la forêt ! Ils débouchaient, en effet, en plein espace, devant un ciel immense* (Châteaubriant, *Lourdines*, 1911, p. 205)

Answer (score -1):

Il est bien question soit de *personnes* soit d'*espaces donnés* dans la nature du sujet de ce verbe ; cependant il me semble qu'il y a une raison qui entraine quand même l'exclusion de « tu ».

La vue d'ensemble suivante des fonctions de l'infinitif dans la phrase (à partir de la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4217)) permet une revue appropriée et une base de déduction ;

> - **1** SUJET
> - **2** ATTRIBUT DU SUJET
> - **3** COMPLÉMENT DIRECT OU INDIRECT d'un autre verbe ou comme COMPLÉMENT D'UN VERBE IMPERSONNEL
> - **4** COMPLÉMENT D'AUTRES ÉLÉMENTS DE LA PHRASE : COMPLÉMENT DU NOM, COMPLÉMENT DE L'ADJECTIF ou COMPLÉMENT CIRCONSTANCIEL
> - **5** APPOSITION

Dans « *Il suffit que tu fasses quelque pas vers la gauche pour déboucher directement sur la porte sud.* » il est clair qu'il s'agit de « **4** », comme l'infinitif est introduit par la préposition « pour ». Il y a bien un verbe impersonnel, mais la prépositions « **pour** » indique un complément circonstanciel ; il faut déterminer quel élément entre dans cette relation avec « déboucher » (suffire) **et** la nature du complément. Du but et de la conséquence, lequel convient ?  La différence entre le but et la conséquence réside dans le fait que le but est une conséquence recherchée ; il est apparent que dans le présent cas qu'il ne s'agit que de conséquence ; prenons un exemple assez courant dans un contexte similaire ;

- Ils ne savaient pas trop où ils allaient dans ce quartier ; ils firent encore une centaine de mètres pour se retrouver dans la rue du Mirail et finalement après une rue populeuse pour rejoindre la porte sud.

Dans l'exemple suivant on peut parler de but ;

- Vous ne savez pas donc comment rejoindre la porte sud ? Il suffit que vous fassiez quelques pas vers la gauche pour rejoindre la porte sud. 
  (*ou, équivalent*) Pour rejoindre la porte sud il suffit que vous fassiez quelques pas vers la gauche. (*Dans le présent ordre, il n'y a pas de doute, il ne peut s'agir que du but.*)

La proposition infinitive serait donc, ce qu'il y a de plus probable, un complément circonstanciel de conséquence du verbe « suffire ».

On se rend compte que l'idée de but est imputable à un être vivant en tant que volonté et donc explique son action alors que la conséquence ne l'est pas. Dans l'énoncé en cause, au vu que le complément implique assez logiquement la conséquence, il est question d'une vérité générale : (pas plus que) faire quelques pas vers la gauche *entraine* déboucher sur la porte sud. Au lieu de cette syntaxe, celle-ci étant hors de doute, on trouve que l'action de quelqu'un en particulier a la conséquence donnée. Cela ne semble pas souhaitable ; bien que cet exemple d'utilisation de l'infinitif soit sujet à une analyse plus difficile et donc plus incertaine que celle pour les exemples afférents  de [contrindication d'utilisation de l'infinitif](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4711) par la BDL, conseils plutôt que règles mais conseils dont je pense qu'ils devraient être scrupuleusement suivis, je crois que le présent exemple est candidat pour figurer dans cette liste-même. Donc on ne devrait pas vraiment dire cela et comme la BDL on peut conclure que l'on dirait plutôt ceci :

> Voyons, la grande rue de Ginza... Il suffit **de faire** quelque pas vers la gauche pour déboucher directement sur la porte sud. Facile.

(Dans cet arrangement  la proposition infinive de verbe « déboucher » a la fonction de complément circonstanciel de « suffire », et celle de verb « faire » en est le complément.)

PS I didn't pay attention to the language used in the question, and went on answering it, merely moved by the import I construed from its first reading, until it was too late. I am sorry for that. I hope that in some day to come I'll find the incentive for doing a translation.